# Display post thumbnail for specific category outside the loop

Tags: categories, loop, post-thumbnails

I'm building a theme that features a section wherein I'd like to have the single most recent post's thumbnail of a single category displayed between the header and blog sections. Something like

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

would work within the loop, but I'm wondering how I can make this work outside of, or separate from the loop.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) with a new [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
<?php 
 if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
 $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large');
 echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
 echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail', array('class' => 'aligncentre')); 
 echo '</a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always do a new wp_query to get the latest post from given category and display its thumbnail etc.. Something like

```
$new_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=your_category_id&showposts=1' );
if( $new_query->have_posts() ): while( $new_query->have_posts ): $new_query->the_post();

the_post_thumbnail();

endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

replace your_category_id with a proper value